# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.GridModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: telerik-grid

I have form with a Telerik grid. Within the grid toolbar, I have a custom button which I would like to open a popup window to insert a new record.

I have followed the [Popup Form with Server/Client Validation in Window - Example](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/window/popup-form-with-server-client-validation-in-window---example.aspx) and modified it to fit my scenario. However, running the application generates the following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Telerik.Web.Mvc.GridModel', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'Web.Models.OwnerViewModel'.

Below is an extract from the view that is hosting the grid

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Owner Listing";
}

@model Web.Models.OwnerViewModel
@{  Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("Window")
    .Title("Add New Owner")
    .Content(@<text>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Owner", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddNewOwnerForm" }))
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone)
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="t-button t-state-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        }
        </text>)
    .Width(400)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Render();
}

<div>
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Web.Models.OwnerViewModel>()
    .Name("Vehicles")
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Custom()
        .Action("Create", "Owner")
        .Name("btnAddNewOwner")
        .Text("Add Vehicle")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnAddNewOwner" })
     )
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(v => v.Id).RouteKey("Id"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
        }).Width(40);
        columns.Bound(v => v.FullName).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(v => v.Telephone).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(v => v.Address).Width(150);
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("Index", "Owner")
        .Update("Edit", "Owner"))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    )
    )
</div>
```

The following is the controller code for the grid

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var owners = _ownerService.ListAll();        
        return View(new GridModel( owners ));
    }
```

and the following is the controller code for Create

```
    public PartialViewResult Create()
    {
        SetSelectionLists();
        var model = new OwnerViewModel();
        return PartialView( "Create", model);
    }
```

I have looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but non seems to address the problem I am facing. I would appreciate any help or a pointer to the right direction.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need set model of view create to GridModel type and return in action of it to GridModel

Comment: The Create view expects a Web.Models.OwnerViewModel which is not an IEnumerable. I do not see how setting the controller action to return a GridModel is going to assist.